# Google Apps Script for copying Goals from one property to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to copy the views from one property to another in Google analytics.When i try to copy Goals its throwing an error.

```
for (var j = 0; j < profiles_src.items.length; j++) {
    var profile_src = profiles_src.items[j];  
    var profile_dest=Analytics.Management.Profiles.insert(profile_src, accountId_dest, webPropertyId_dest);
    sheet.getRange(row, 10).setValue(profile_dest.name);
    sheet.getRange(row, 11).setValue(profile_dest.id);
    var filter_src=Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.list(accountId_src, webPropertyId_src, profile_src.id)
    //var goal_item=goal_src.items[0]; 
    sheet.getRange(23, 2).setValue(filter_src);    
    var filter_dest = Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.insert(filter_src.items[0], accountId_dest, webPropertyId_dest, profile_dest.id);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: Where is the "copy Goals" code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Put some:

```
Logger.log("The value of my variable is: " + aVariableName);
```

Statements into your code, then VIEW the LOG to see what is happening.  You can also step through the code line by line.